# General slice type in golang?

Tags: types, go, slice

I'm having some difficulties trying to extend slice types into a general type in Go. I have created a sample code to explain my problem. [play ground version](http://play.golang.org/p/LfeiVqiXR_)

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Sequencer interface {
    Mean() float64
}

type Sequence []int

func (s Sequence) Mean() float64 {
    sum := 0.0
    for _, el := range s {
        sum += float64(el)
    }
    return sum / float64(len(s))
}

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    b := Sequence(a)
    fmt.Println(b.Mean())
    fmt.Println(b[:2].Mean())
    c := Sequencer(b)
    fmt.Println(c.Mean())
    fmt.Println(c[:2].Mean())
}
```

Last line of the main() function returns an error saying that variables of type Sequencer cannot be sliced:

> cannot slice c (type Sequencer)

Is there a way of defining a general type of slices (int, float64, string,...) without hiding the cool indexing capabilities of slices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any type that provides the methods declared in an interface definition can be stored in an interface variable of that type.  While the actual value you are storing is a slice, any type could implement the interface.  And since in many cases it is impossible to statically determine the dynamic type of an interface variable, the language doesn't let you peek below the covers without an explicit type assertion.

If slicing is something you expect types implementing your `Sequencer` type to implement, then the simple solution is to extend the interface to include such a method:

```
type Sequencer interface {
    Mean() float64
    Slice(start, end int) Sequencer
}
```

This can be implemented for your `Sequence` type in the obvious way:

```
func (s Sequence) Slice(start, end int) Sequencer {
    return s[start:end]
}
```

You can then get the mean of a slice using the method:

```
fmt.Println(c.Slice(0, 2).Mean())
```

You can experiment with this solution here: http://play.golang.org/p/UMuqOarLUu

Comment: I like this proposal the most, as makes slicing general without any type assertion, but I still think it's a pity not being able to make use of the convenient indexing style [:] where we don't need to know the slice dimensions...

Answer (score 5):

You have

```
type Sequencer interface {
    Mean() float64
}

c := Sequencer(b)
```

Therefore, the variable `c` contains a value of some type which satisfies the `Sequencer` interface; the type has a `Mean` method. That's all we can say, no more, no less. It does not imply that the variable `c` value can be sliced. Therefore, the slice expression `c[:2]` is invalid. For example, we could define a type `Map` which satisfies the `Sequencer` interface but cannot be sliced. If you want to slice `c` then assert that it is of a type that can be sliced, for example, `c.(Sequence)[:2]`.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Sequencer interface {
    Mean() float64
}

type Sequence []int

func (s Sequence) Mean() float64 {
    sum := 0.0
    for _, el := range s {
        sum += float64(el)
    }
    return sum / float64(len(s))

}

type Map map[string]float64

func (m Map) Mean() float64 {
    sum := 0.0
    for _, v := range m {
        sum += float64(v)
    }
    return sum / float64(len(m))

}

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    b := Sequence(a)
    fmt.Println(b.Mean())
    fmt.Println(b[:2].Mean())
    c := Sequencer(b)
    fmt.Println(c.Mean())
    fmt.Println(c.(Sequence)[:2].Mean())
    m := Map{"one": 3.14159, "two": 2.718}
    fmt.Println(m.Mean())
}
```

Output:

```
2.5
1.5
2.5
1.5
2.929795
```

Comment: Yeah +1. I didn't include an assertion sample (lazy of me really :/)

Answer (score 2):

Of course. This is no different from any other language that has the concept of an interface.

You're trying to call the "operator" `[]` on a type that doesn't support it - `Sequencer` (an interface). Whereas, `Sequence` does  - because it takes on the properties of a slice, hence why the calls to `b.Mean` and `b[:]` work.

If this were C# for example, you're essentially trying this:

```
interface Sequencer {
    float Mean();
}

Sequencer c = ...;

c[any_index] ... // error - interface doesn't have this operator defined
```

The limitation here is that you cannot implement operator overloads in Go. If you could - then you would be able to just add that to the interface and all would tick along as expected.

Comment: Is your answer then that there is no way in Go of implementing an operator overload on the "[]" defined in slices?

Comment: No.. my answer is that you cannot define operators.. and therefore your interface cannot define one. When you're trying to access a variable through the "eyes" of an interface.. it won't see it. You therefore have to go with your custom `typedef` you have there for `type Sequence []int` and access it that way.

Comment: But what if I don't know a priori the type of the slice? I won't be able to index a general slice type then?

Comment: No - since Go doesn't have generics. You would be looking at type assertions or switching on a type to do that.. and it would get very ugly very quickly. There might be a way to do it with the _reflect_ package though..